# Convert from decimal to binary and octal

Tags: c, converting, number-systems, binary

I wrote a program that implements an algorithm that converts from decimal to binary and octal

Please criticize my implementation. What else can I do to improve?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>

int n, option, flagOctal;
int a[100];

void  baseConversion10Base2(long long x){
    int D = 0;
    while(x){
        a[++D] = abs(x % 2);
        x /= 2;
    }
    for(int i = D; i > 0; i--)
        printf("%d", a[i]);
}


void baseConversion10Base8(long long nrDecimal)
{
    int D = 0;
    while(nrDecimal){
        a[++D] = abs(nrDecimal % 8);
        nrDecimal /= 8;
    }
      for(int i = D; i > 0; i--)
      printf("%d", a[i]);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if(argc == 1)
    {
        printf("No arguments were entered");
    return 0;
    }
    else
    if(argc == optind)
    {
    printf("Only optional parameters have been entered");
    return 0;
    }
     else
    {
        opterr = 0;
        while((option = getopt(argc, argv, "o")) != -1){
        switch(option){
        case 'o':
            flagOctal = 1;
            break;
        default:
            ;
        }
        }
    if(optind == argc)
    {
    printf("Only optional parameters have been entered");
    return 0;
    }

    printf("Positive numbers converted to ");
    if(flagOctal == 1) printf("octal: "); else printf("binar: ");
    for(int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
  {
    if(strcmp(argv[i], "0") == 0)
    {
    printf("0");
    continue;
    }
    char *a = argv[i];
    long long nr = atol(a);
    if(nr == 0)
    printf("X ");
    else
    {
    if(flagOctal == 1)
    {
        baseConversion10Base8(nr);
        printf(" ");
    }
    else
    {
        baseConversion10Base2(nr);
        printf(" ");
    }
    }
  }

    printf("\nNegative numbers converted to ");
    if(flagOctal == 1) printf("octal: "); else printf("binar: ");
    for(int i = 1; i < optind; i++)
    {
    char *a = argv[i];
    long long nr = atol(a);
    if(nr < 0)
    {
    printf("-");
    if(flagOctal == 1)
        baseConversion10Base8(abs(nr));
    else
        baseConversion10Base2(abs(nr));
    printf(" ");
    }
    }   


 }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `conversieBaza10Baza8`?

Comment: sorry, i edited now

Answer (score 3):

The global variables make it harder to reuse your code.  They seem to be unnecessary anyway: the integer variables are used only in `main()`, and `a` could be scoped into the `baseConversion` functions.

Depending on target platform, the size of `a` might not be large enough to represent the binary value of a `long long`, which can have `CHAR_BIT * sizeof (long long)` bits.

The conversion functions mix computation and output, again making re-use more difficult (and `baseConversion10Base8` could be replaced with a simple `printf("%llo", …)`).

We're using `getopt()`, so should be including `<unistd.h>` rather than `<getopt.h>` (which declares `getopt_long()` and `getopt_long_only()`).

Since `optind` is initialised to `1`, the test `if (argc == optind)` immediately following `if (argc == 1)` can never be true.

We don't need `else` when the preceding block leaves the function.

The `switch` should include a case for `getopt()` returning `'?'` when the user provides an unrecognised option.  The `default` case that does nothing can be removed.

`atol()` is a poor choice for converting string input to integer, as it doesn't distinguish between failure and an actual zero value.  Prefer `strtoll` instead.

There's a value truncation hidden here:

> ```
>    baseConversion10Base8(abs(nr));
> ```

`abs(nr)` will truncate its argument to `int`.  We should be using `llabs()` to correctly convert a `long long`.  Note that there's a failure case on 2's-complement systems when the input is `LLONG_MIN`, as `-LLONG_MIN` exceeds `LLONG_MAX`.

Instead of `flag_octal`, we could just store a pointer to the function to use:

```
    const char *base_name = "binary";
    void (*conversion_function)(long long int) = baseConversion10Base2;
```

```
        case 'o':
            base_name = "octal";
            conversion_function = baseConversion10Base8;
```

```
    printf("Positive numbers converted to %s: ", base_name);
```

```
    printf("-");
    conversion_function(llabs(nr));
    printf(" ");
```

`printf()` is somewhat heavyweight for printing single characters or fixed strings - prefer `putchar()` and `fputs()` respectively.

"Binary" is misspelt as "binar" in two of the printed messages.

Comment: `CHAR_BIT * sizeof (long long)` may be too small, as index 0 is not used. Then again, with one bit used for sign…

Comment: @greybeard, I missed that we never write to index 0 - thanks for spotting.  Yes, using only positive numbers dodges that particular bullet, but I thought it wise to re-word anyway.

Answer (score 2):

- The code presented could be more readable.

  - Starting with comments telling what "everything" is there for.
  - Naming: integers/numbers *are not decimal*.
    Representations are, unless specified otherwise.
  - Code layout:
    The indentation is inconsistent
    After a conditional return, there is no need for an `else`.
    Conventionally, `else if` is kept together, and the if-(else-)statement is not indented another level.
- Don't Repeat Yourself.

```
    /** terminate program execution with the specified exit code
     *  and a message to out */
    void terminate(int exit_code, char const *message, FILE *out)
    {
        if (NULL != message && NULL != out) {
            fputs(message, out);
            fputc('\n', out);
        }
        exit(exit_code);
    }
    /** leave the program with a message to stdout */
    void leave(char const *message) {
        terminate(0, message, stdout);
    }
        
    /** print x as an (unsigned) number base 2, 
     *  most significant digit first. */
    void print_base2(long long x) {
        print_base(x, 2);
    }
    /** print x as an (unsigned) number base 8, 
     *  most significant digit first. */
    void print_base8(long long x) {
        print_base(x, 8);
    }
    /** print x as an (unsigned) number base base, 
     *  most significant digit first. */
    void print_base(unsigned long long x, int base) {
        if (base < 2 || 10 < base)  // CHAR_MAX? 10 + 'Z' - 'A' + 1?
            leave("base out of range");
        char a[CHAR_BIT * sizeof (long long)];  // ample for 2 < base
        int n = convert2base(x, base, a, sizeof a);
        if (n < 0)
            leave("conversion failed unexpectedly");
        while (0 <= --n)
            putchar('0' + a[n]);
    }

    /** store digits base base for n in digits, least significant digit first.
     *  return number of digits if length is sufficient, else -1. */
    int convert2base(unsigned long long n, int base, char digits[], int length)
    {
        if (NULL == digits || length <= 0)
            return -1;
        int d = 0;  // digit
        digits[0] = 0;
        while (n && d < length) {
            digits[d++] = n % base;
            n /= base;
        }
        if (0 != n)
            return -1;
        return d;
    }
```

Comment: My C is beyond rusty. The alternative presented doesn't show much about layout.

Answer (score 0):

This may give you computational boost. Although as pointed out by others in comment this may be "The" code produced by modern day compilers.

```
while(x){
    a[++D] = abs(x % 2);
    x /= 2;
}
```

can be written as

```
while(x){
    a[++D] = x&1;
    x = x>>1;
}
```

And writing

```
while(nrDecimal){
    a[++D] = abs(nrDecimal % 8);
    nrDecimal /= 8;
}
```

as

```
while(nrDecimal){
    a[++D] =  !(nrDecimal & 7)
    nrDecimal=nrDecimal>>3;
}
```

Comment: "Definitely"?  Don't be so sure: that's the kind of transformation that any decent compiler will perform.  I'd expect performance to be identical (on a 2's complement system, anyway - it would be incorrect elsewhere).

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. While this might be a good answer on stackoverflow, it is not a good answer on Code Review. A good answer on Code Review contains at least one insightful observation about the code. Alternate code only solutions are considered poor answers and may be down voted or deleted by the community. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is the *logical not* of `nrDecimal & 7`?

Comment: Another problem with this kind of approach is that sometimes it hides an even better compiler optimization.  Because compilers tend to assume that bit fiddling operations are already optimal, so they don't analyze them the same way that they do mathematical operations.  I'm not saying to never attempt this kind of optimization, but one should only do it on code that definitely needs optimized and should follow up with metrics that test both approaches.

Comment: @TobySpeight : I agree. Should have given more thought for all systems as well. It appears to be super confidant. Shall edit

Comment: @pacmaninbw : Thank you for giving the link. Shall check.